# Encapsulation confusion

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how to correctly encapsulate objects.

Example:

```
struct Car {
    int wheels = 0;
    int doors = 0;
};

class A{
    Car myCar;

public:
// 1st method
    Car getCar() const { return myCar; }
    void setCar(Car c) { myCar = c; }
// 2nd method
    Car &getCarReference() { return myCar; }
// 3rd method
    Car *getCarPointer() { return &myCar; }
};
```

As I understand 1st method makes a copy of my structure which is fine if structure is small like shown in example. But what if structure contains 100 000 double values. Should I then use 2nd method? Or declare structure pointer, dynamically allocate memory and use 3rd method?

Comment: Read about [*return value optimization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and [*copy elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). And never micro-manage optimizations, and never do it prematurely. Always write good, maintainable and readable and *working* code. Then if the performance is not "good enough" you measure, profile and benchmark to find the bottlenecks and optimize those only.

Comment: The title of the question is a bit misleading. The question seems to be about the sematics of value types versus the one of reference types, which is unrelated to encapsulation.

Comment: Please read about `const` reference too. It should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you want is this:

Some class, A, wraps another class, Car. It should be possible to access the Car element of A, however, you can't make the Car element public since there is potential for inconsistency of the wrapper class if somebody should then change that element (if not, then simply make it public).

If so, go with a const reference:

```
const Car& getConstCarReference() const { return myCar; }
```

This is then called like

```
const Car& car = instanceOfA.getConstCarReference();
```

And after that, you can use any constant call on car.

Returning a pointer, by the way, is in most cases a bad idea. Essentially, whenever you think of returning a pointer, you should be able to clearly argue why returning a pointer is the best solution.

That said, I recommend to abstain from method names like "get" and "set". Make the code looking more like a clockwork instead of handling organic classes. I'd recommend you to name the method simply car, as in `const Car& car() const { return m_car; }`, the member variable in hungarian notation as you see (not important that you use hungarian notation, but I recommend to clearly mark member variables, at least if the class is not very small. Going with something like `_car` or `car_` for the member also works well.)